# using shared memory with php and c?

Tags: php, c, ipc, shared-memory

Can you use shared memory to communicate between php scripts and c program in windows?

The c program runs all the time and uses memory mapped files ie:

```
handle1 = CreateFileMapping(
 (HANDLE)0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, sizeof(byte)*BUFFER_SIZE, "my_foo" );

hView = (LPINT) MapViewOfFile(handle1, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
```

For the PHP scripts can I just use the below code to open the memory mapped file created by the c program?

```
$shmkey = @shmop_open(ftok("my_foo", 'R'), "a", 0644, $buffer_size);
```

or are c memory mapped files and php shared memory different things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP shmop functions are just wrappers for the underlying [POSIX functions](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmop), which doesn't seem to be available under windows.

From the [PHP manual](http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/ref.shmop.php):

> Note:  Versions of Windows previous to Windows 2000 do not
>   support shared memory. Under Windows,
>   Shmop will only work when PHP is
>   running as a web server module, such
>   as Apache or IIS (CLI and CGI will not
>   work).

Appearently PHP emulates this behaviour within apache, but since it isn't available in the stand alone binaries it will hardly integrate with the windows equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to allow PHP to access shared memory that was created and written to by a Windows application. I achieved this by creating my own php extension (called php_gsect.dll). This may not be what you want but my php_gsect attaches to the global section and reads (or writes) a number of bytes which I can then manipulate.

FYI: My windows application is retreiving dynamic trend data from another system and putting the data into a named global section. The php web page is accessing the data from the global section and creating a chart (using the ESJ chart library).