# Auto-updating Webpage content

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, linux

I am working on a system that has a bunch of sensors communicating with a linux machine. I need to make a web interface for this to display status of sensors and automatically update them when the status of any of the sensors changes(or just automatically update them every few seconds).

The code for reading sensors is all in C code. What are the options for pushing the sensor data to the web browser automatically or even by continuously requesting the data?

I have considered the following scheme:
Allocate shared memory in the C program for the sensor data, which can be read by a server side script like php. Then have some ajax or something requesting the data on a loop or timer event.

Is it possible to push the data to the client rather than pull?

I really do not have any experience with php/ajax, so any tips on how to implement this would be great.

Some key elements I do not know:

-How to do timing in javascript

-How to get some sort of structured data in javascript on the fly from a request to the server(eg php page reading the sensor data)

Comment: I guess a soul purpose of "Userinterface and server" is User always initiate talking...However lets wait for professional's answer

Comment: IMHO this question is waaaaayyyyy to basic (instead of specific) for this site. You can find LOTS of links to introductory web programming teaching pages through Google. We CAN discuss pushing vs. pulling in web apps (using chunked encoding it is possible to have long-running AJAX calls used for server "push-like" messages), but that would be pretending - that's very specific step 53 in the course of web app development, and for the purpose of THIS question we have to start with step 1.

Comment: @krio [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_\(programming\))

allows for push.

Comment: This is a very general question, a bit too general for a specific answer with actual code examples. I'd say the easiest way is for your client webpage to make an ajax request every x seconds to update itself with the latest data. You'd use JavaScript's `setTimeout` to do that. You can transmit a serialised form of structured data with JSON (and deserialise on client-side). The easiest way to implement ajax is with a library such as jQuery.

Comment: Ook thanks, I probably should read about comet, However user must interact atlases once with server in order to register IP. Yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say , to getting data , you have two solutions :

**A) Pulling data with ajax**

You easily can do some periodical task with setInterval :

```
setInterval(callbackserver, PERIOD_MILLIS);
```

If you use a framework like jquery, there is plenty of plugin for periodical updating.

**B) Pushing Data with a js server**

Data can be push to the browser instead of pulling it. For that you need a server based on protocol like **Comet**. Check [this project](http://www.ape-project.org/) for more information

> How to get some sort of structured data in javascript on the fly from a request to the server

json seems to be a perfect solution for structured data accross langage.

> I have considered the following scheme: Allocate shared memory in the
>   C program for the sensor data, which can be read by a server side
>   script like php

Why not simply make a deamon in C and get data from it via PHP with a `exec("mydeamon -data")` command for exemple

Comment: The C code is running continuously doing other stuff/calculations. I don't want to keep restarting the C program, or are you saying create a daemon in C strictly for messaging with the other C program that is managing sensors?

Comment: I don't really know what is possible with your C code , but a deamon for messaging your other C program could be a solution. Using a shared memory with something like memcache could do the job too : http://amix.dk/blog/post/19414

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot generally push data using HTTP. You will have to poll the server. (There are alternatives that can push, if you are interested. See [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29))
2. You can use Ajax to dynamically send request to the server. See [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html) for details. It is pretty simple.
3. You have to send this Ajax periodically. You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) for this.

setTimeout("yourAjaxRequestFunction",delay);

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you/your company can afford it, I'd recommend [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/).
If your application is written in C then C++ would likely be more familiar than PHP or Javascript.
It can also handle pushing data to a web page using either ajax pull or web sockets.

Answer (score 0):

- Ajax would be a good choice to pull the data periodically. It's completely client-side and very easy to start with. check some examples on the internet.
- And for the server-side, you need something that takes the data from C. Sharing memory between C and PHP would be tedious. You can simply create or update a text file by C. And place this file in the home folder of the web server (apache perhaps)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680763/using-shared-memory-with-php-and-c for the trouble of sharing memory between C and PHP

Comment: running linux...i dont see any issue with shared memory access from php based on that link which is about windows.